# I want a image but nither assest image nor network image is loading on screen

Tags: flutter

image is not loading in output in my screen .soo plz anyone help me in solving this

```
  Container(
   decoration: const BoxDecoration(
     image:DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(''))
   ),
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you added your image into the `pubspec.yaml` file like this:

```
assets: 
- images/image1.jpeg
- images/icon.png
```

I suggest use the `child` of the Container and not the decoration.
Also, you could use `Image.Asset` instead, specifing `height` or/and `height`:

```
Image.asset('images/icon.png', height: 20)
```

Documentation [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/pubspec) and [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Network Images on flutter take time to appear.

But if it still continues then
Check Internet Permission setting in `andoidmanifes.xml` file

Answer (score -1):

Using Asset image is not a good solution because it makes the app size larger..
The solution is that you need to use:

```
Container(
child: Image.network('') //your image source
)
```

And if that is not the case.. the image you are using is invalid but not exactly invalid. Meaning it does not end with an image format in the end.. like (.jpg,.png etc.)